# Is this Entity-Relationship Diagram Correct?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, rdbms

In this image the blue part is is that Multiple employees are being ordered by one manager according to directed line but in The second part which is red The arrow is reversed which means that multiple managers are now ordering a single employee but according to me the red part is wrong because its doing completely reverse of the blue part am i right here?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRjHB.jpg)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Boxes clearly don't even mean the same sort of thing in the 2 diagrams. So the arrows don't even mean the same thing either. The 2nd/red/bottom diagram isn't even an ER diagram. Quote the slide/video where you got this saying what the picture is saying & what the 2 notations mean. (This is why my standard comment about giving text for text & giving images only when augmenting says **include a legend/key**.) (Also there are many many notations & methods so you always need to give a reference to or definition of yours.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That presentation "ER Model: Connectivity of Relationships" by Parteek Bhatia is unclear & confused. The bottom diagram isn't ER & its lines between instances are not explained & don't agree with earlier slides & neither does the bottom diagram in the next slide. The bottom lines are between entity instances. (Ie entities. The boxes in the top/ER diagram(s) actually represent entity classes/types.) Connected instances form a tuple of instances that satisfy the relationship represented by a top line. Earlier, such lines didn't have arrows & were between dots. In later slides top lines are replaced by diamonds with lines. Confused. Bad presentation.